# Join dataset with case class spark scala

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset, bloom-filter

I am converting a dataframe into a dataset using case class which has a sequence of another case class

```
case class IdMonitor(id: String, ipLocation: Seq[IpLocation])
case class IpLocation(
    ip: String,
    ipVersion: Byte,
    ipType: String,
    city: String,
    state: String,
    country: String)
```

Now I have another dataset of strings that has just IPs. My requirement is to get all records from `IpLocation` if `ipType` == "home" or IP dataset has the given IP from `ipLocation`. I am trying to use bloom filter on the IP dataset to search through that dataset but it is inefficient and not working that well in general. I want to join the IP dataset with `IpLocation` but I'm having trouble since this is in a Seq. I'm very new to spark and scala so I'm probably missing something. Right now my code looks like this

```
def buildBloomFilter(Ips: Dataset[String]): BloomFilter[String] = {
    val count = Ips.count
    val bloomFilter = Ips.rdd
      .mapPartitions { iter =>
        val b = BloomFilter.optimallySized[String](count, FP_PROBABILITY)
        iter.foreach(i => b += i)
        Iterator(b)
      }
      .treeReduce(_|_)
    bloomFilter
  }

val ipBf = buildBloomFilter(Ips)
val ipBfBroadcast = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(ipBf)

idMonitor.map { x => 
    x.ipLocation.filter(
       x => x.ipType == "home" && ipBfBroadcast.value.contains(x.ip)
    )
}
```

I just want to figure out how to join `IpLocation` and `Ips`

Comment: At the end, do you want a dataset of `IpLocation` or a dataset of `Seq[IpLocation]` ?

Comment: At the end I want `Seq[IpLocation]`

Comment: I updated my answer to match your desired output

Comment: @VincentDoba in your solution we will filter out home ip type before we join, but I want the final result to have records which are either home ipType or are present in the `Ips` dataset (that means it could possibly be not of home ipType)

Comment: I updated my answer to use an `or` condition instead of `and`: I now filter after the join, that is now a left outer join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sample:**

Starting from your case class,

```scala
case class IpLocation(
    ip: String,
    ipVersion: Byte,
    ipType: String,
    city: String,
    state: String,
    country: String
)
case class IdMonitor(id: String, ipLocation: Seq[IpLocation])
```

I have defined the sample data as follows:

```scala
val ip_locations1 = Seq(IpLocation("123.123.123.123", 12.toByte, "home", "test", "test", "test"), IpLocation("123.123.123.124", 12.toByte, "otherwise", "test", "test", "test"))
val ip_locations2 = Seq(IpLocation("123.123.123.125", 13.toByte, "company", "test", "test", "test"), IpLocation("123.123.123.124", 13.toByte, "otherwise", "test", "test", "test"))

val id_monitor = Seq(IdMonitor("1", ip_locations1), IdMonitor("2", ip_locations2))
val df = id_monitor.toDF()
df.show(false)

+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |ipLocation                                                                                            |
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |[{123.123.123.123, 12, home, test, test, test}, {123.123.123.124, 12, otherwise, test, test, test}]   |
|2  |[{123.123.123.125, 13, company, test, test, test}, {123.123.123.124, 13, otherwise, test, test, test}]|
+---+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and the IPs:

```scala
val ips = Seq("123.123.123.125")
val df_ips = ips.toDF("ips")
df_ips.show()

+---------------+
|            ips|
+---------------+
|123.123.123.125|
+---------------+
```

**Join:**

From the above example data, explode the array of the `IdMonitor` and join with the `IPs`.

```scala
df.withColumn("ipLocation", explode('ipLocation)).alias("a")
  .join(df_ips.alias("b"), col("a.ipLocation.ipType") === lit("home") || col("a.ipLocation.ip") === col("b.ips"), "inner")
  .select("ipLocation.*")
  .as[IpLocation].collect()
```

Finally, the collected result is given as follows:

```
res32: Array[IpLocation] = Array(IpLocation(123.123.123.123,12,home,test,test,test), IpLocation(123.123.123.125,13,company,test,test,test))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can explode your array sequence in your `IpMonitor` objects using `explode` function, then use a left outer join to match ips present in your `Ips` dataset, then filter out on `ipType == "home"` or ip is present in `Ips` dataset and finally rebuild your `IpLocation` sequence by grouping by `id` and `collect_list`.

Complete code is as follows:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, collect_list, explode}

val result = idMonitor.select(col("id"), explode(col("ipLocation")))
  .join(Ips, col("col.ip") === col("value"), "left_outer")
  .filter(col("col.ipType") === "home" || col("value").isNotNull())
  .groupBy("id")
  .agg(collect_list("col").as("value"))
  .drop("id")
  .as[Seq[IpLocation]]
```